# Bash complex redirection (what does this command do)?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, process-substitution

I recently was messing with an AWS virtual machine setup script. The documentation says to include this line:

```bsh
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1
yum -y update
echo "Hello from user-data!"
```

so that you can later access the virtual machine logs from the AWS website.

But AWS doesn't matter here, I was wondering: what does the first command even do?
I know basic bash redirections like `>` or even `2>&1` but the fact that there are so many nested redirections (`exec > >`, `-s 2>dev/console`) makes me lose my mind.

Here's how I think how a step-by-step explanation goes:

1. So we have `2>&1` at the end. This means `copy stdout to stderr`. This will be important later.
2. `exec > >`. What? I know `>file` is an alias for `1>file`. So is this basically `exec 1>1>(tee ...| logger ...)`? Why not `exec>(tee ...|logger...)` then?
3. `exec > >(tee /var/log-user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console)`
   The `(tee ...|logger ...)` bracket receives stdout from exec and puts it inside a file. The problem is that tee is supposed to read from stdin and output to file. But here we only pass it stdout. Is this basically `1|tee file`? I know pipes don't work with descriptor ids like that.
4. Tee takes stdout and prints it to logger's stdin. Then logger descriptor "2" (which contains both stdin and stderr) to /dev/console. But why pipe then? logger already has access to stdout in descriptor number 2.

Comment: There are so many wrong assumptions in that, I suggest you start by experimenting with simpler expressions, step by step. First: `>(...)` process substitution is a kind of expansion, not of redirection: the shell will create a pipe, where the read end will be the stdin of the process inside `>(...)`, and it will expand to _name_ of the writing end in the shell: `echo foo >(cat)` => `foo /dev/fd/63`. Since all expansions happen before redirections, guess what will `echo foo > >(cat)` do.

Comment: And keep in mind that the shell does redirections from left to right, the `2>&1` `stderr = stdin` will happen at the very end, and NOT affect the process inside `>(...)`.

Comment: `exec >` redirects all output of the current shell process to `>(...)`. The shell will no longer print output to the screen, writing it to `>(...)` instead.

Comment: Grab a copy fo the full (info) bash manual, and read the chapter on redirections and the one on subprocesses carefully